# HTML FontFace is working in safari and not in stimulator - Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: html, webview, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have an HTML page which uses fontface for japanese font. It worked perfectly in browsers. when I checked on html5 mobile application in Appcelerator Titanuim, it failed in both Stimulator and Device. please guide me how to overcome this. my syntax is :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Japanese';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Japanese'), url('css/Japanese.ttf') format('truetype');
}
.Japanese {
font-family: Japanese, sans-serif;
}
```

Thanks in Advance, GANESH M

Answer (score 0):

Check your paths.. That is usually the problem for custom fonts. It needs to be local / relative scoped to be cross platform. Also, you can debug this by using the [Safari Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) to see if it is picking up the font and if there are other problems.